# Python - Convert certain fields of a dict into a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following Python dict:

```
{
  'parameter_010': False, 
  'parameter_009': False, 
  'parameter_008': False, 
  'parameter_005': 'C<sub>MAX</sub>', 
  'parameter_004': 'L', 
  'parameter_007': False, 
  'parameter_006': 'R', 
  'parameter_001': 'Foo', 
  'id': 7542, 
  'parameter_003': 'D', 
  'parameter_002': 'M'
}
```

As seen there are a number of fields named `parameter_nnn` where `nnn` is a sequential number. Some are `False` and others have values populated.

I would like to generate a list with just the `parameter_nnn` field values which, but just the ones which contains a given value, sorted by number from `001` upwards.

So in this specific case the desired output is:

```
["Foo", "M", "D", "L", "CMAX", "R"]
```

Which would be the pythonic way of doing this? I obviously can start iterating but wondering if there is something better than that.

Python 2.7

Comment: That's JSON not a python dict (hint: `false`)

Comment: Totally true, I printed the JSON instead of the Python dict. I edited the question, now it is a Python dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, assuming you know that you are working with a JSON and how to deserialize:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = """{
...   "parameter_010": false,
...   "parameter_009": false,
...   "parameter_008": false,
...   "parameter_005": "CMAX",
...   "parameter_004": "L",
...   "parameter_007": false,
...   "parameter_006": "R",
...   "parameter_001": "Foo",
...   "id": 7542,
...   "parameter_003": "D",
...   "parameter_002": "M"
... }"""
>>> d = json.loads(s)
```

If your `parameter_nnn` always and strictly follow this format, you can simply sort the items filtered by your requirements (since lexicographical sorting is what you want!):

```
>>> sorted([(k,v) for k, v in d.items() if v and k.startswith('parameter')])
[('parameter_001', 'Foo'), ('parameter_002', 'M'), ('parameter_003', 'D'), ('parameter_004', 'L'), ('parameter_005', 'CMAX'), ('parameter_006', 'R')]
```

If you just want the values, just do another pass:

```
>>> [v for _,v in sorted([(k,v) for k, v in d.items() if v and k.startswith('parameter')])]
['Foo', 'M', 'D', 'L', 'CMAX', 'R']
>>>
```

Note, you are going to have to loop somehow...

A more readable version:

```
>>> selection = [(k,v) for k, v in d.items() if v and k.startswith('parameter')]
>>> [v for _,v in sorted(selection)]
['Foo', 'M', 'D', 'L', 'CMAX', 'R']
```

#### EDIT: Major Caveat

Note, if the values can be `0` or any other falsy value that you actually want, then this won't work, so for example:

```
>>> pprint(d)
{'id': 7542,
 'parameter_001': 'Foo',
 'parameter_002': 'M',
 'parameter_003': 'D',
 'parameter_004': 'L',
 'parameter_005': 'CMAX',
 'parameter_006': 'R',
 'parameter_007': False,
 'parameter_008': False,
 'parameter_009': False,
 'parameter_010': False,
 'parameter_011': 0}
>>> selection = [(k,v) for k, v in d.items() if v and k.startswith('parameter')]
>>> [v for _, v in sorted(selection)]
['Foo', 'M', 'D', 'L', 'CMAX', 'R']
```

So if you want to filter instances of *`False`* specifically (and not `0`) then you have to use *`is`*:

```
>>> selection = [(k,v) for k, v in d.items() if v is not False and k.startswith('parameter')]
>>> [v for _, v in sorted(selection)]
['Foo', 'M', 'D', 'L', 'CMAX', 'R', 0]
```

Comment: This is very useful, I just modified it a bit and used an intermediate variable to make second pass easier to read.

Comment: @M.E. btw, I added an edit with a caveat regarding the possibily of falsy values you may want to keep, e.g. `0`

Comment: That's relevant. I want to filter instaces of `False` only. Thanks for the caveat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
list(zip(*sorted(i for i in d.items() if i[0].startswith('parameter') and i[1])))[1]

# ('Foo', 'M', 'D', 'L', 'C<sub>MAX</sub>', 'R')
```

**Explanation**

- We filter for 2 conditions: key starts with 'parameter' and value is Truthy.
- `sorted` on `d.items()` returns a list of tuples sorted by dictionary key.
- `list(zip(*..))[0]` returns a tuple of values after the previous filtering and sorting.
- I haven't dealt with `<sub></sub>` as I have no idea where this is from and what logic should be applied to remove this (and other?) tagging.

Comment: The `<sub></sub>` was misleading I shold had removed it in the question, it is just part of the string and no action needs to be done. I find anyway juanpa.arrivillaga easier to follow/read.

Comment: No problem, `zip` is sometimes a bit "non-linear".

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

dicty = {
  "parameter_010": False, 
  "parameter_009": False, 
  "parameter_008": False, 
  "parameter_005": "CMAX", 
  "parameter_004": "L", 
  "parameter_007": False, 
  "parameter_006": "R", 
  "parameter_001": "Foo", 
  "id": 7542, 
  "parameter_003": "D", 
  "parameter_002": "M"
}
result = []

od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dicty.items()))
for k, v in od.iteritems():
    if v != False and "parameter" in k:
        result.append(v)
print(result)
```